# python http server that can be stopped while processing a request, according to the client side state

Tags: python, http, tcp, request

I implemented a HTTP server using python `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class. This class is for processing certain request that takes several minutes and return a response to the client (actually it's not a web server. using http just a convenient wrapper of tcp).

What I want to implement is: when I send a SIGINT to a client I want the server to stop processing the request and turn to be waiting mode to accept new response.

Do you have any clean idea to implement this? (Or, any standard idiom for this?)

Comment: Can you modify the client code to catch the SIGINT signal?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes, but I cannot send stop request to server because server is processing the long-taking request...

Comment: After a short research, I found ThreadingMixin is close to what I want